# Entity Framework 7 - accessing related entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

My problem is accessing related entities in Web App on 2nd level relation. Didn't find proper answer related to EF7.

Let's take following sample of 3 classes: one-to-many - x - many-to-one.

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Buy> Buys { get; set; } = new List<Buy>();
}

public class Buy {
    public int BuyId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}

public class Book {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Buy> Buys { get; set; } = new List<Buy>();
}
```

With context.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Buy> Buys { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Collection(c => c.Buys).InverseReference(c => c.Person)
            .ForeignKey(c => c.PersonId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .Collection(i => i.Buys).InverseReference(i => i.Book)
            .ForeignKey(i => i.BookId);
}
```

Person Controller - Details view.

```
// _context present in given scope
public IActionResult Details(int? id) {
    var person = _context.People
            .Include(c => c.Buys)
            .Where(c => c.PersonId == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

With this configuration I intended to be able to fetch from Person model, not only Buys info, but also related further books. Like following in part of View.

```
@model <project>.Models.Person
// (...)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonId)      // ok - person
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonName)    // ok - person

@foreach (var item in Model.Buys) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.BuyId)     // ok - buy
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Book.Name) // null - book
}
```

Do I need to code additional references in fluent API or do further includes in entity model to be able to access Item data from Person level?

Comment: Better practice is to make custom model with the required data and fill it in the controller, then pass it to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF 7 beta7 you can also use the [`ThenInclude`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes:-January-8,-2015) method to include several levels:

```
var person = _context.People
                     .Include(c => c.Buys)
                     .ThenInclude(b=>b.Book)
                     .FirstOrDefault(c => c.PersonId == id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should include `Book` like you did with `Buys`. I mean:

```
var person = _context.People
        .Include(c => c.Buys.Select(x => x.Book))
        .Where(c => c.PersonId == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

But actually if you working with MVC it's better to create `ViewModel` Class that have all data that you need on particular View rather than have your EF classes on View.

Comment: I didn't want to create ViewModels cause I have only 2 multi-level fetches in the project. IMO, it would be cluttered. 

Cannot chain Includes with the vision of the proper relational scope like You  suggested. However @octavioccl suggested very neat ThenInclude - works like charm.

Comment: @baftinho ok, you were right, i change my code to working version